EKS cluster with managed nodegroups in private subnets fail with ‘Instances failed to join the Kubernetes cluster’
I successfully created an EKS cluster with managed node groups in private subnets using CloudShell and the following YAML configuration.
Now, I want to achieve the same setup using Terraform. I tried the example code for managed node groups, but I encountered an error stating:
"Instances failed to join the Kubernetes cluster."
When creating the cluster with YAML, I faced the same error unless I included privateNetworking: true. Unfortunately, this parameter is not available in Terraform, so I assume there is something else I need to specify to resolve this issue.
YAML configuration for successfully creating a cluster with managed node groups:
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: clusterFoo
  region: eu-central-1
  version: "1.31"

vpc:
  id: vpc-123
  subnets:
    private:
      eu-central-1a:
        id: subnet-234
      eu-central-1b:
        id: subnet-345
  securityGroup: sg-567

cloudWatch:
  clusterLogging:
    enableTypes: ["api", "audit", "authenticator", "controllerManager", "scheduler"]

managedNodeGroups:
  - name: nodeFoo
    amiFamily: AmazonLinux2
    ami: ami-678
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 1
    minSize: 1
    maxSize: 1
    volumeSize: 41
    privateNetworking: true
    overrideBootstrapCommand: |
      #!/bin/bash
      /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh clusterFoo
 
addons:
  - name: vpc-cni
    version: latest
    attachPolicyARNs:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
  - name: kube-proxy
    version: latest

Terraform script that fails with the error: 'Instances failed to join the Kubernetes cluster.
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "~> 20.0"

  cluster_name    = "clusterFoo"
  cluster_version = "1.31"

  bootstrap_self_managed_addons = false
  cluster_addons = {
    coredns                = {}
    eks-pod-identity-agent = {}
    kube-proxy             = {}
    vpc-cni                = {}
  }

  cluster_security_group_id = "sg-567"

  # Optional
  cluster_endpoint_public_access = false
  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true

  # Optional: Adds the current caller identity as an administrator via cluster access entry
  enable_cluster_creator_admin_permissions = true

  vpc_id                   = "vpc-123"
  subnet_ids               = [
    "subnet-234",
    "subnet-345"
  ]
  
  # control_plane_subnet_ids = ["subnet-xyzde987", "subnet-slkjf456", "subnet-qeiru789"]

  # EKS Managed Node Group(s)
  eks_managed_node_group_defaults = {
    instance_types = ["t2.medium"]
  }

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    example = {
      # Starting on 1.30, AL2023 is the default AMI type for EKS managed node groups
      ami_id = "ami-678"
      # ami_type       = "AL2023_x86_64_STANDARD"
      instance_types = ["t2.medium"]

      min_size = 1
      max_size = 1
      desired_size = 1
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}


If I am not mistaken, that is usually a problem with networking. Do the private subnets have a NAT gateway defined?
